# flutter New version of Google Maps SDK for iOS available: 4.1.0.0

Tags: ios, flutter, google-maps

I have latest  google_maps_flutter: ^1.0.6 installed
But when I run the Application on iOS Simulator. My app runs Fine but google map is not working.

I get the message in log

```
Google Maps SDK for iOS version: 3.9.0.0
New version of Google Maps SDK for iOS available: 4.1.0.0
```

I tried to add Google map 4.1.0.0 to PodFile But I am getting error when I try to Install Pod or Update

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue before until I run following commands:-

Step:-1  Open a terminal and go to the directory containing the Podfile:

```
cd ios
```

Step:-2  Run this command :-

for intel processor

```
pod outdated
```

for m1 processor

```
arch -x86_64 pod outdated
```

Step :-3 Update your pods:-

for intel processor

```
pod update
```

for m1 processor

```
arch -x86_64 pod update
```

Step -4 : Finally clean the project & rebuild  the project:-

Run this command to clean the project-

```
flutter clean
```

And forget uncomment this line in podfile

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
```

Answer (score -2):

Hello I have this issue as well as seen in the screenshot. Now it is working for me after I added the following permissions into Info.plist

```
    <key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string></string>
```

And now my app works again! I hope this helped you!

[image: 2]

[image: 1]